# RUBY - Currency Exchange Rate Calculator

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a currency converter in Ruby which will calculate the exchange rate between two currencies on a given date.

I have a data file containing test data (date, currency from, currency to). The test data is in EUR, so all rates are converted to EUR and then to the target currency.

So far I have 3 files (`Exchange.rb`, `Test_Exchange.rb`, `rates.json`):

`Exchange.rb`:

```
require 'json'
require 'date'
module Exchange
  # Return the exchange rate between from_currency and to_currency on date as a float.
  # Raises an exception if unable to calculate requested rate.
  # Raises an exception if there is no rate for the date provided.
  @rates = JSON.parse(File.read('rates.json'))

  def self.rate(date, from_currency, to_currency)
    # TODO: calculate and return rate
    rates = u/rates[date] # get rates of given day
    from_to_eur = 1.0 / rates[from_currency] # convert to EUR
    from_to_eur * rates[to_currency] # convert to target currency
  end
end
```

`Test_Exchange.rb`:

```
require_relative 'Exchange.rb'
require 'date'

target_date = Date.new(2018,12,10).to_s
puts "USD to GBP: #{Exchange.rate(target_date, 'USD', 'GBP')}"
puts "USD to JPY: #{Exchange.rate(target_date, 'PLN', 'CHF')}"
puts "DKK to CAD: #{Exchange.rate(target_date, 'PLN', 'CHF')}"
```

`rates.json`:

```json
{
  "2018-12-11": {
    "USD": 1.1379,
    "JPY": 128.75,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.845,
    "DKK": 7.4641,
    "GBP": 0.90228,
    "HUF": 323.4,
    "CHF": 1.1248,
    "PLN": 4.2983
  },
  "2018-12-10": {
    "USD": 1.1425,
    "JPY": 128.79,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.866,
    "DKK": 7.4639,
    "CAD": 1.5218,
    "GBP": 0.90245,
    "HUF": 323.15,
    "PLN": 4.2921,
    "CHF": 1.1295,
    "ISK": 140.0,
    "HRK": 7.387,
    "RUB": 75.8985
  },
  "2018-12-05": {
    "USD": 1.1354,
    "JPY": 128.31,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "CZK": 25.886,
    "DKK": 7.463,
    "GBP": 0.88885,
    "HUF": 323.49,
    "PLN": 4.2826,
    "RON": 4.6528,
    "SEK": 10.1753,
    "CHF": 1.1328,
    "HRK": 7.399,
    "RUB": 75.8385,
    "CAD": 1.5076
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what to add in the Exchange.rb file to allow the user to input a date and the two currencies to compare exchange rates.

Running `Exchange.rb` does nothing. I'm guessing it wants a date and currency parameters input?

Running `Test_Exchange.rb` works because the date and currencies are bootstrapped in.

I found almost the same question posted here a couple years ago, but the thread is now closed, and the solution was incomplete. Hoping someone can help me!

RUNNING EDIT:

`Exchange.rb`:

```
require 'json'
require 'date'
module Exchange
  # Return the exchange rate between from_currency and to_currency on date as a float.
  # Raises an exception if unable to calculate requested rate.
  # Raises an exception if there is no rate for the date provided.
  @rates = JSON.parse(File.read('rates.json'))
 
 #Grab Date and Currencies from User
  
  puts "Please enter a Date (YYYY-MM-DD)"
  input_date = gets.chomp
  puts "The Date you entered is: #{input_date}"
  
  puts "Please enter a 3-letter Currency Code (ABC):"
  input_curr_1 = gets.chomp
  puts "The 1st Currency you entered is: #{input_curr_1}"
  
  puts "Please enter a 2nd 3-letter Currency Code (XYZ):"
  input_curr_2 = gets.chomp
  puts "The 2nd Currency you entered is: #{input_curr_2}"
  

def self.rate(input_date, input_curr_1, input_curr_2)
    
    # TODO: calculate and return rate
    rates = @rates[input_date] # get rates of given day
    from_to_eur = 1.0 / rates[input_curr_1] # convert to EUR
    from_to_eur * rates[input_curr_2] # convert to target currency
  end
end
```

I think I have to use a put and a get to capture the user date input?  Then the same for each of the two currencies?  Of course, my syntax for the date stuff is all wrong..

So I managed to use the gets and put functions.  Now all that's left is somehow calling the rates.json file and comparing the user inputs to the existing data..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happened when you put `ruby get user input` into a search engine?

Comment: "I'm guessing it wants a date and currency parameters input?" All it does is define a function; you need to get input, *call the function using that input*, and *display the result*. The `Test_Exchange.rb` shows examples of the latter two steps using hard-coded input.

Comment: *"I think I have to use a put and a get to capture the user date input?"* -- You need to use `gets`. https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-chomp-gets/

Comment: so i need to define a date variable as gets.chomp?  Then rates.json needs to be parsed to make sure the user input date exists?  Thanks for the comments!